# Labeling a loop on a node in tikz with specified "out" and "in" angles

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

I'm using \draw with parameters "out" and "in" to make loops on a node. I'd like to label these loops, but I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to do this. None of the examples of labeled edges or loops I've found via search use the out/in parameters.

Here is a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node at (0,0) (0) {node};

\draw [->] (0) to [out=135,in=45,looseness=8] (0);
\draw [->] (0) to [out=300,in=30,looseness=8] (0);
\draw [->] (0) to [out=240,in=150,looseness=8] (0);

\node at (0,1.4) {label 1};
\node at (1.8,-.4) {label 2};
\node at (-1.8,-.4) {label 3};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice I've labeled the loops simply by adding new nodes and fine-tuning their positions to match the loops. Of course, this is less than desirable if I want to change the position of the central node.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically just need to place `node [<options>] {<text>}` immedately after `to[<options>]`.

(Note that the `minimal` class should in general not be used, `article` is better. See [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided))

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node at (0,0) (0) {node};

\draw [->] (0) to [out=135,in=45,looseness=8] node[above] {label1} (0);
\draw [->] (0) to [out=300,in=30,looseness=8] node[right] {label2} (0);
\draw [->] (0) to [out=240,in=150,looseness=8] node[below left] {label3} (0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect. I thought it was something this simple. Just couldn't get the right syntax. Thanks again.